# Add a class depending on number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

What would be a good way to add a class to a series of elements depending on how many of them existed?

so in this case if there are two or less items the class is "half"
- if there are less than 8 it should be the "quarter" class applied to them.

Is there a way to add/remove a class depending on how many "item" (s) there are in a section?

```
<section>
 <div class="item half"> 1 </div>
 <div class="item half"> 2 </div>
 </section>


   <section>
 <div class="item quarter"> 1 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 2 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 3 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 4 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 5 </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: I don't see how without JavaScript, Is this dynamically generated? If yes, it should be done through it.

Comment: @P.Lalonde there is a pure css-way actually: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/quantity-ordering-with-css/

Comment: @zerkms That's insane. Otherwise, I think the only other way is to give the `<div>` elements like `class="countMe"` and then do a `document.getElementsByClassName("countMe").length` to get the number of elements. *DISCLAIMER:* Doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @aznbanana9 it's crazy indeed. CSS has never been an easy path to do anything ))

Comment: Yes, the .item(s) are going to be dynamically generated and need to change depending on how many of them their are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('section').each(function(i, sect){
    var itemsInSection = $(sect).children('.item');
    var count = itemsInSection.length;
    if(count < 3){
      itemsInSection.addClass('half');
    }else if(count < 8){
      itemsInSection.addClass('quarter');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <div class="item half"> 1 </div>
 <div class="item half"> 2 </div>
 </section>


   <section>
 <div class="item quarter"> 1 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 2 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 3 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 4 </div>
 <div class="item quarter"> 5 </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: This works well! but how would i make it so it only counts the ".item".  Because if I have other elements that I don't want to count.

Answer (score 3):

You can always get the count of your elements like

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
var count = elems.length;

if(count < 2) {
// add class half
} else if (count < 8) {
// add class quarter
}
```

Comment: would I just put that in between script tags like this? <script type="text/javascript">
    
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
var count = elems.length;

if(count < 2) {
 add class .one
} else if (count < 8) {
 add class .two
}

</script>

Comment: Yes, also you need to have code to set the appropriate class to the div. Put the script tags just above closing body tag or in head. If you are putting in head make sure your code is getting executed only after DOM is ready.